# Combining WIF STS Forms Authentication and Single Sign On with SAML and ADFS 2.0 in the same ASP.NET application

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, wif, adfs2.0, ws-federation

does anyone have experience in setting up Single Sign On with SAML and ADFS 2.0 on an application that already has an existing WIF STS setup with Forms Authentication. Is it possible to have both Forms authentication setup and an ADFS setup in the same ASP.NET application? To configure ADFS requires changes in the web.config which would overwrite the changes that were made to setup the STS that is used for Forms authentication. When I tried to combine the current setup with ADFS I was not able to get to the AD FS server address https://Site/adfs/ls , this would give me compilation errors saying “Could not load type request validator”. I looked this error message up and it has something to do with WIF “WS-Federation passive protocol”. This is how I knew that the 2 setups were conflicting with each other. I am however able to see the Federation Metadata on the server when I go to https://Site/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml , the XML outputs so that’s a good sign. I am new to Federated Authentication so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to have a login form within your application that uses ADFS to validate credentials?  If not, can you explain exactly what you are trying to do to "combine" them?

Comment: @stephen.vakil... Currently there is a portal that when a user logins in with their credentials they get redirected to an STS login page with Forms authentication. I want to use AD FS to Single Sign On to a third party site from inside the portal. So the user would click on a link and the user would have already been authenticated so they would be taken directly to the third party site. Does that make sense?